# php preg_split simple pattern task

Tags: php, regex

Im not familiar with preg_split, but i need to split string
`'_bsdhh__1022232781'` i need to get number value so i've tried preg_split but im not sure how to properly set patter i need to split this string by "_" and appending number from 0-9  for example `"_1"`But it's not working, and i need to get entire number value, so there is something like substring ? i was using explode, but it's useless in case more _ values. It's seems likes a newbie question,but i need to do fast fix on server side. Looking forward for helpful reply.

```
$exploded = preg_split('_\[0-9]', $str);
```

Comment: Please post your attempt so far. How else should we help with it?

Comment: As i said, before i was using explode but it's useless in case with many "_" I've tried few combinations with preg_split pattern but they dosent work.

Comment: Why is explode useless? Split it with "_" and then loop through the array and check it with is_numeric.

Comment: Why don't you at least enable `error_reporting` when something doesn't work? Delimiters missing. Also, matching would be more reliable than splitting with such a crude pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version without regex:

```
$string = '_bsdhh__1022232781';
$array = explode("_", $string);

function findNumber($values) {
    foreach($values as $value) {
        if(is_numeric($value)) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
}

$number = findNumber($array);
```

Comment: Thanks, what a shame i missed that option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `preg_match()` to extract a token from a subject:

```
<?php
$subject = '_bsdhh__1022232781';
$pattern = '/([0-9]+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);
print_r($tokens);
```

Obviously the regex might not be final, it depends on the exact definitions of *what* you want to extract and how the subjects might look like. For that this approach might be a better starting point:

```
<?php
$subject = '_bsdhh__1022232781';
$pattern = '/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*/i';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);
print_r($tokens);
```

Answer (score 0):

To split with "_", to find the number, you can use preg_match, as @arkascha show.

**Code**

```
$str = "_bsdhh__1022232781";
$exploded = preg_split('/_/', $str); 
print_r($exploded);
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: No need to use regex-based splitting when it's just one given character.

Comment: True AMDcze. It is not the best solution, but he can now change this example to learn more about